# Can Selenium IDE generate tests in C# for MSTest

Tags: selenium, mstest

I have started using the selenium plugin for firefox for web automated testing.  Is their a way when you generate the code for the tests in C# you can get it to create unit tests using MSTest instead of NUnit, which is the default.  Not a biggie, but would be useful to know all the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, no. The formatter only outputs NUnit code. However you may want to take a look at this blog, http://koenwillemse.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/custom-c-formatter-for-selenium/, which creates a custom formatter using MSTest.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the critical link to script is no longer valid on this page.